# How to add AngularJS in JSF page in intellijidea

Tags: angularjs, jsf, intellij-idea

I previously add "angular.min.js" into Intellij-idea for my projects that include JSP pages, but now i want to add agular into JSF page. When i add "angular.min.js" file "ng-app" and "ng-controller" are unknown by intellij! i don't know why, but i add lib and angular.js and when i type ng-app it was unknown by intellij and become red! Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by add dependency in POM Files:
    
            de.beyondjava
            angularFaces-core
            2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs - like Netbeans and IntelliJ - try to verify your JSF very strictly. They know the list of "legal" JSF attributes from the taglib file provided by the component library (Mojarra, MyFaces, BootsFaces, PrimeFaces or AngularFaces). The difference between JSP and JSF is that JSP basically is already the final HTML code, while JSF generates the HTML code. So adding `ng-app` to one of the existing JSF components changes nothing. The attribute won't appear in the HTML code.

One solution is to add AngularFaces. Actually, this does a lot more than simply allowing you to add `ng-app` to JSF components. For instance, it converts `<div>` tags to first class citizens of JSF, which comes in handy in many situations.

If you need a less invasive solution, and if you're using JSF 2.2 or above, simply use pass-through attributes. They'll do the trick just as well. By the way, the implementation of AngularFaces does just that: it recognizes the attributes of AngularJS and converts them automatically to pass-through attributes.